# Separating joined words on uppercase letter

Tags: python, regex

Using Python, I must write a script that essentially "cleans" a data text file. So far I've taken out all the unwanted characters or replaced them with acceptable characters (e.g., a dash `-` can be replaced with a space). Now I've gotten to the point where I have to separate words that are joined together. Here is a snippet of the first 15 lines of the text file

```
AccessibleComputing  Computer accessibility
AfghanistanHistory  History of Afghanistan
AfghanistanGeography  Geography of Afghanistan
AfghanistanPeople  Demographics of Afghanistan
AfghanistanCommunications  Communications in Afghanistan
AfghanistanMilitary  Afghan Armed Forces
AfghanistanTransportations  Transport in Afghanistan
AfghanistanTransnationalIssues  Foreign relations of Afghanistan
AssistiveTechnology  Assistive technology
AmoeboidTaxa  Amoeba
AsWeMayThink  As We May Think
AlbaniaHistory  History of Albania
AlbaniaPeople  Demographics of Albania
AlbaniaEconomy  Economy of Albania
AlbaniaGovernment  Politics of Albania
```

What I want to do is separate the words that are joined at the point where the uppercase letter occurs. For example I want the first line to look like this:

```
Accessible Computing  Computer accessibility
```

The script must take the file input and write the result to an output file. This is what I currently have and it's not working at all! (not sure if I'm on the right track or not either)

```
import re

input_file = open("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned2.txt",'r')
output_file = open("C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned3.txt",'w')

for line in input_file:
    if line.contains('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'):
        newline = line.

output_file.write(newline)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

Comment: What I want to do is insert a Whitespace right before the upper case letter that is joined to the previous word. I saw that topic earlier but I can't figure it out with file input :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to split words with the following regex:

```
import re, os

input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'

with open(input_file, 'r') as f_in:
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in.readlines():
            p = re.compile(r'[A-Z][a-z]+|\S+')

            matches = re.findall(p, line)
            matches = ' '.join(matches)

            f_out.write(matches+ os.linesep)
```

Assuming data.txt contains text you pasted in your post, it will print:

```
Accessible Computing Computer accessibility
Afghanistan History History of Afghanistan
Afghanistan Geography Geography of Afghanistan
Afghanistan People Demographics of Afghanistan
Afghanistan Communications Communications in Afghanistan
Afghanistan Military Afghan Armed Forces
Afghanistan Transportations Transport in Afghanistan
Afghanistan Transnational Issues Foreign relations of Afghanistan
Assistive Technology Assistive technology
Amoeboid Taxa Amoeba
As We May Think As We May Think
Albania History History of Albania
Albania People Demographics of Albania
Albania Economy Economy of Albania
Albania Government Politics of Albania
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best method, but it is simple.

```
from string import uppercase

s = 'AccessibleComputing Computer accessibility'

>>> ' '.join(''.join(' ' + c if n and c in uppercase else c 
                     for n, c in enumerate(word)) 
             for word in s.split())
'Accessible Computing Computer accessibility'
```

And by the way, this is how you should do your file read/write:

```
f_in = "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned2.txt"
f_out = "C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\Python\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned3.txt"

def func(line):
    processed_line = ... # your line processing function
    return processed_line

with open(f_in, 'r') as fin:
    with open(f_out, 'w') a fout:  
        for line in fin.readlines():
            fout.write(func(line))
```

Comment: thank you! i will try this out and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
re.sub(r'(?P<end>[a-z])(?P<start>[A-Z])', '\g<end> \g<start>', line)
```

This will insert a space in between each lower case upper case letters next to each other (assuming you only have English characters.)

Comment: There's also unicode in the file (it's 300k lines long)